# doxygen doesn't document my variables in c++

Tags: c++, doxygen

First of all there is 2 other question like this in stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem.

This is my source code:

```cpp
/** @file
* \brief Brief description of this file.
*
* Detailed description here
*/


/** The main function. I will now try to document
 *  variables within this main function.
 */
int main() {

  int a; /*!< Description about variable in main function */
  return 0;
}
```

The comment after `int a;` appears in `html` output without pointing to the variable name.

```
◆ main()
int main    (       )   

The main function.

I will now try to document variables within this main function.

< Description about variable in main function
```

Another way is to write my comment in a line before defining the variable just like the comment before main function but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Doxygen was made to document the **interface**.  Your `a` is a local variable, part of the implementation.

Comment: When you say "there is 2 other question like this in stackoverflow" please make a link to them, can give people ideas and the y don't have to invent the wheel again etc. The comment from @Eljay is correct.